# Can all connected locally compact groups be written as a product of abelian and compact subgroups?

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Is it true that given a connected locally compact group $G$, there must be abelian subgroups $H_{1},\dots, H_{n}$ and a compact subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G$ is homeomorphic to $H_{1}\times H_{2}\times\cdots\times H_{n}\times K$?

If so, can anyone supply a reference?

Any response is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if I only asked the map $(h_{1},\dots,h_{n},k)\mapsto h_{1}\cdots h_{n}k$ to be a homeomorphism.  Are you saying that would work?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that if you changed the direct product to semi-direct product, that there wouldn't be such subgroups of the *new* group which satisfy the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For every connected locally compact group $G$ there is a maximal compact subgroup $K$, and there  exists $d\in\mathbf{N}$ (unique) such that $G$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^d\times K$. See https://mathoverflow.net/a/140638/14094

So to conclude, it is enough to show that if $G$ is not compact, then it has a closed subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$, and this is standard.